# What's wrong with this code?

Tags: 7, redirection

```
function welcome_menu() {
  $item=array();
  $item['welcome'] = array(
    'title' => 'welcome',
    'access callback' => 'welcome_init', 
    'page callback' => 'welcome_test',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  ); 

  return $item;
}

/*
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function welcome_init() {
  if (empty($GLOBALS['user']->uid)&& arg(0)!='welcome') {
    drupal_goto('welcome');
  }
}

function welcome_test() {
  $output = 'welcome';
  return $output;
}
```

I want to auto redirect the anonymous users to the login page, and avoid that an authenticated user can see this page. how I use `user_login_block()` as page callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An access callback must return a boolean value that is `TRUE` when users can access the page, and `FALSE` when they cannot access the page; it should not redirect users to other pages.

Drupal has a function that returns `TRUE` when the user is anonymous.

```
function welcome_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['welcome'] = array(
    'title' => 'welcome',
    'access callback' => 'user_is_anonymous', 
    'page callback' => 'welcome_test',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  ); 

  return $item;
}
```

The code is similar to the one used by the User module.

```
function user_menu() {
  // …

  $items['user/login'] = array(
    'title' => 'Log in', 
    'access callback' => 'user_is_anonymous', 
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  );

  // …
  return $items;
}
```

To show the login block using your menu callback, you need to change your function code with the following one.

```
function welcome_test() {
  return drupal_get_form('user_login_block');
}
```

[hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_init/6) is not invoked for cached pages, and Drupal normally caches the pages for anonymous users (when it is set to do so).

Comment: thank you.got it. but how to make the page callback call the login block?

Comment: and why this can;t work?  function welcome_init() {
      if (empty($GLOBALS['user']->uid)&& arg(0)!='welcome') {
        drupal_goto('welcome');
      }
    }

Comment: @enjoylife: Use `drupal_get_form('user_login_block')` and return the value you obtain from the function.

Comment: when i access the example.com as an anonymous, there is no redirect to the welcome page. why? when i access example.cpm/test. it can access the login block.

Comment: user_is_anonymous and 'user_login_block' is the user module function, why in my custom module.,i can use it. thank you.

Comment: @enjoylife: If you have enabled the page caching for anonymous users, `hook_init()` doesn't have effect on the cached pages, except when it adds JavaScript or CSS files to the page.

Comment: but when i access the example.com or other page that not welcome in my site as an anonymous,how to make it redirect to the welcome page? and user_is_anonymous and 'user_login_block' is the user module function, why in my custom module.,i can use it. thank you.

Comment: @enjoylife: You can use the function defined from any modules that are enabled. If the module is not always enabled (which means is not one of the modules that are required by Drupal to work) then your module needs to declare its dependency from that module; user.module is necessary for Drupal to work, and you don't need to declare its dependency from user.module. You can use the functions defined from other modules as callbacks; if the function is not in the module file, then you can use `file` and `file path` to tell Drupal which is the file to load to get that function.

Comment: To redirect anonymous users independently from the page being viewed, you should use `hook_init()`, but your module can only work when the page caching for anonymous users is not enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious thing is that it does not follow Drupal's coding standards at all. It makes it very difficult to read.

hook_init() is it's own hook, it should not be used as an access callbacks. Access callbacks need to return either TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: how to correct the code? thank you.